# Does GetElementsByTagName() return value on-the-fly?

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, getelementsbytagname

I have some question about internals. Does [`GetElementsByTagName()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementsbytagname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) read all the elements requested store on an array and return it or return the value on-the-fly (like using `yield`)? I hope it's clear

Comment: You could always look at the [source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/HtmlDocument.cs,5fadf8b295e0cc1a).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It returns an `System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElementCollection`, which implements neither `IEnumerable` nor `IEnumerator`. That means it doesn't work like `yield`.

`yield` indicates that a method is an iterator. In addition, for a method to be an iterator, its return type must be `IEnumerable`, `IEnumerable<T>`, `IEnumerator`, or `IEnumerator<T>`.

See also:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx